# struts2 How read value iterator from jsp to action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator

I'm new to java and struts2, please help.
from an action I have read and process a list created in a jsp

**my problem is, how do I have access to data from an action of an iterator?**

**JSP PAGE**

```
<s:iterator value="settoriList" var="myObj">
<tr>
<td>
   <s:if test="#myObj.selected == 1">
      <s:checkbox name="selected"   fieldValue="%{cdSettore}" checked="checked"/>
      <s:property value="cdSettore" />
   </s:if>
   <s:if test="#myObj.selected == 0">
      <s:checkbox name="selected"  value="false" fieldValue="%{cdSettore}"  />
      <s:property value="cdSettore" />
   </s:if>
</td>
<td><s:property value="dsSettore" /></td>
<td><s:property value="dtIniVali" /></td>
<td><s:property value="dtFineVali" /></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
 </table>
  <s:hidden name="cdConve" />
  <s:hidden name="process"   value="saveSettori"/>
</s:form>
```

**Here is how I am trying to access the data**

```
private List<GenSettori> settoriList;

public List<GenSettori> getSettoriList() {
    return settoriList;
}
public void setSettoriList(List<GenSettori> settoriList) {
    this.settoriList = settoriList;
}

private String[] selected;

public String[] getSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(String[] selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

--------
   settoriList = new ArrayList<GenSettori>();
   System.out.println("list sett: "+settoriList);
    for(int i=0;i<getSettoriList().size();i++){
     if (getSelected()[i]!=""){
         System.out.println("not selected "+getSelected()[i]);
  }      
   }

---------
```

My page is formed by selected field, a description and a date.

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: provide code for object `GenSettori`

Comment: and what is `cdSettore`,`dsSettore` ... give some explainantion and also provide names of your files please

Comment: I exactly did not understand what you want to do. **getselcted()** will get values which are selected only.. **how can you find `not selected` in `selected ones`?**

Also you are initializing an array and making loop of its size!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get string array from jsp to action class by following lines

In jsp

```
<s:hidden name="cdSettore" value="%{cdSettore}"></s:hidden>
```

If you want you can use

```
<s:if test="#myObj.selected == 0">
   <s:hidden name="cdSettore" value="%{cdSettore}"></s:hidden>
</s:if>
```

to get not selected once

in action class

```
private String[] cdSettore;

public void setCdSettore(String[] cdSettore) {
    this.cdSettore = cdSettore;
}
public String[] getCdSettore() {
    return cdSettore;
}

for(int i=0;i<getCdSettore().length;i++){
    System.out.println("not selected :"+getCdSettore()[i]);
}
```

Or you can do this

In jsp

```
<s:hidden name="cdSettore" value="%{cdSettore}"></s:hidden>
<s:if test="#myObj.selected == 1">
  <s:checkbox name="selected" fieldValue="%{cdSettore}" checked="checked"/>
  <s:property value="cdSettore" />
</s:if>
<s:if test="#myObj.selected == 0">
  <s:checkbox name="selected"  fieldValue="%{cdSettore}"  />
  <s:property value="cdSettore" />  
</s:if>
```

In action class

```
  for(int i=0;i<getCdSettore().length;i++){
        int flag=0;
        for(int j=0;j<getSelected().length;j++){
            if(getCdSettore()[i].equalsIgnoreCase(getSelected()[j]))
            {
                flag++;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
         System.out.println("not selected :"+getCdSettore()[i]);
        }
    }
```